Represent a line as an equality with 0
I have the following line in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$r\equiv x=y=z$$
I can also represent $r$ with a set of equalities like:
$$r\equiv\begin{cases}
2x = y + z \\
2y = x + z \\
2z = x + y
\end{cases}$$
However, I need to express it in a form like $f(x,y,z)=0$. I tried with conditions like $2x-y-z=0$, but it is necessary to characterize the line with all of the above equations. Thus, is there a way to write $r$ as an equality of a function of $x,y,z$ to 0?

What about $f(x,y,z)=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2$?

Note that the above expression encodes "$x=y$" in the first term and "$y = z$" in the second term.  This is an entirely standard way to encode the conjunction of two equations in one equation if you are working with real numbers (or nicer subsets of the reals).  This doesn't work over the complex numbers.

@EricTowers Though $\lvert x-y\rvert + \lvert y-z\rvert$ should work over the complex numbers?

What does the notation $r\equiv x=y=z$ mean? If you mean that $r$ is the set of all triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $x = y = z$, you should write it in this form.

@kritiker-der-elche $r$ is defined as a line whose points met the condition $x=y=z$
